# MVC EditorTemplate Does Not Render

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, razor

Apologies if this has already been answered before, I've trawled the database but none of the suggestions seem to answer my problem.

I'm new to using EditorTemplates and I have an EditorTemplate called Address.cshtml which is meant to be used to edit Address objects.

Address Class

```
public class Address
{
    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Company Name cannot be longer than 30 characters")]
    public string Line1 { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address Line 1 is required")]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Address Line 1 cannot be longer than 30 characters")]
    public string Line2 { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(ConvertEmptyStringToNull = false)]
    [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Address Line 2 cannot be longer than 30 characters")]
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
etc..
}
```

Address.cshtml

```
@model Address

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line1, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Address Line 1" } })

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line2, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Address Line 2" } })

@Html.EditorFor(x => x.Line3, new { htmlAttributes = new { placeholder = "Address Line 3" } })

etc..
```

Usage

```
<div>
    @{
        Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckoutDetails.DeliveryAddress);
    }
</div>
<div>
    @{
        Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckoutDetails.BillingAddress);
    }
</div>
```

I've also tried

```
@{
    Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckoutDetails.DeliveryAddress,"Address");
}
```

The `DeliveryAddress` and `BillingAddress` properties are of type `Address`, the Editor Template is named `Address.cshtml` and I've placed it in the `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` folder.

In addition all my views (and this Editor Template) are precompiled  using RazorGenerator (I'm not sure if this has a bearing).

My problem is that having done all this the Editor Template does not render, it's simply blank and there doesn't appear to be any error messages. All help gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered the answer to this. I was using the following construct in my view

```
@{
  Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckoutDetails.DeliveryAddress);
}
```

I found that using the following instead works

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CheckoutDetails.DeliveryAddress)
```

I'm not too sure why the subtle difference causes the issue.